# Parent and Child Component Styling in React for Multiple Accordions

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

So in my react project I have a bunch of components who's parent components all get called and formatted in the index.js file I am about to paste. The index.js file exports a main function where all previous components are living into the app.js and then the DOM/index.js. Here is my code for the first index.js file:

```
import {React} from 'react'
import SocialFooter from '../components/SocialMediaFooter'
import Header from '../components/Header'
import SkillsAccordion from '../accessories/SkillsAccordion'
import WorkAccordion from '../accessories/WorkAccordion'
import styled from 'styled-components'



const MasterAccordionContainer = styled.section`
    position: relative;


`;
const Main = (props) =>{
    return(
    <div>
        <div>
        <Header />
    </div>
    <div>
        <MasterAccordionContainer>
        <SkillsAccordion />
        <WorkAccordion style={props.children}/>
        </MasterAccordionContainer>
       
    
    </div>

    
    
    <div>
        <SocialFooter />

    </div>

    </div>


    )}



    //add all react components here and export to app.js


export default Main;
```

Here is my task:
I need to somehow style the WorkAccordion component and the SkillAccordion component so that they sit next to eachother rather than one of top of the either. Here is a screenshot of what I mean.
[image: ReactPicture]

So I need those two Accordions to be side by side instead of on top of one another. I believe this has something to do with me needing to reference absolute and relative positions in the styling off of one another but, I am not sure how to do that. Thank you all in advance for any help you can give me!

Edit:

[image: display:flex]

when adding `display:flex;` the Accordion gets distorted, see picture above

Edit:
After adding the styling for flexbox directly to the container `MasterAccordioinContainer` it all worked perfectly!

Picture below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you set `display: flex;` to your parent, its children will be side by side by default, unless you set `flex-direction: column` (default is `row`). you could also add the the style `flex-wrap: wrap` to become responsive for smaller devices. a good guide on flexbox you can find it here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Can you explain how I would create that parent child relationship with what I have. Also, thank you very much for the help.

Comment: also, see edit above as to how the display:flex; distorts the Accordion

Comment: flex-direction: column; solved the above edited error but, I still do not understand how to get the children parent relationship there

Comment: did you apply to `MasterAccordionContainer`? this would be the parent where you should apply `display: flex`

Comment: you apply the `display: flex` to the wrapper container, which seems to be this section `MasterAccordionContainer`. I would say this problem could happen if your accordion is using a fragment to wrap its content instead of some tag element

Comment: This worked perfectly with a few tweaks!!

Comment: Glad it worked out :) there is also this little game that might help you out practice display flex. https://flexboxfroggy.com/https://flexboxfroggy.com/